# Store posts data according to timestamps in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have been trying to create a structural format of posts with the help of Wordpress `get_posts` function. The structure with I am creating is based on the post timestamps. So basically the posts having the same timestamps will be collected together and displayed on the page. The structure is something like

1. TIMESTAMP (Example 12345678)

   POST 1 with timestamp 12345678

   POST 2 with timestamp 12345678
2. TIMESTAMP (Example 87654321)

   POST 1 with timestamp 87654321

   POST 2 with timestamp 87654321

Now the approach I have been trying to achieve is to store the posts having similar timestamps in an array. So the array would be something like

`array( $timestamp => array($post1, $post2) )`

By this I think I will be able to get each post besides its timestamp and then I would just display the posts attached to a timestamp.

The problem is that I cannot store multiple values in the same timestamp and I am not sure if my code has problems or what.

**THE CODE:**

```
    foreach ($my_posts as $post) {

        // Get the current post details
        $post_id    = $post->ID;
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id  );
        $date       = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'timeline_event_date', true );

        // Change to format of the date ( Month Date, Year)
        $parsed = date_parse_from_format('n-d-Y', $date);
        $old_date_timestamp = mktime(
                $parsed['hour'], 
                $parsed['minute'], 
                $parsed['second'], 
                $parsed['month'], 
                $parsed['day'], 
                $parsed['year']
        );
        $new_date  = date('F j, Y', $old_date_timestamp);
        $post_unix_timestamp = strtotime($new_date);

        $eventHTML[] = array( $post_unix_timestamp => array( $post ) );

    }
```

Can somebody help me out here please? Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line

```
$eventHTML[] = array( $post_unix_timestamp => array( $post ) );
```

with this line

```
$eventHTML[$post_unix_timestamp][] = $post;
```

Comment: WOW, such simple solution. I was stuck at this for previous 24 hours mate. Thank you so much for help ..